# Caching in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index I indicated `index.store.preload: ["*"]`
In order to preload data into the file system cache. The entire index occupies 27 Gb, about 45 Gb is allocated to the cache in the system, and all this memory is full, it turns out that not only 27 Gb is crawled into the cache, but also something else. Is it possible to somehow find out how much the total index space in the cache will occupy? Also, I don’t understand the difference between the file system cache and the use of `indices.fielddata.cache`. Which one will be more practical for a faster search? Does it make sense to use both options?

Answer (score 0):

1. The data on the disk has been compressed markedly before being synced. So there's always relatively apparent inflation after being loaded into memory. As the specific inflation rate is related to data type, field count or index options, it's fundamentally impossible to give an accurate estimation about the final size in the memory.
2. FieldData is docValue of Lucene, which is used to sort or agg. If you just want to search by single query, this cache is of little help. By comparison, file system cache is always used by elasticsearch and constructs the foundation of ES, both in query and filter context.